# multiple input select change condition

Tags: jquery, select, input, conditional-statements, show

how can i make multiple input select change condition to view diference div output with jquery?

here is my code

```
<-- input select one -->    
<select id="property">
<option selected="selected" value="">Choose one</option>
<option value="rumah">House</option>
<option value="apartemen">Apartment</option>
</select>

<-- input select one -->    
<select id="method">
<option selected="selected" value="">Choose one</option>
<option value="buy">Buy</option>
<option value="rent">Rent</option>
</select>

<div id="view-box">
<-- output to change base on condition (house buy, house rent, apartement buy etc) -->
here..
</div>
```

thankyou

Comment: What do you want.? what is your question.? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the change in value in a `<select>` tag with jQuery's `.change()` function. Since you did not specify what you want to execute on each set of condition. I just made a simple way to show the changes:

```
$('#property, #method').change(function(){
    var propertyVal = $('#property').val();
    var methodVal = $('#method').val();
    var n = propertyVal+' '+methodVal;

    $('#view-box').text(n);

});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/2tb6H/1/)